# Unity SetActive(true) not working after setting it to false at first?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Heirarchy structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR0WO.png)

```
using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
        private Rigidbody rigidbody;
        public Vector3 LaunchVelocity;
        private AudioSource audiosource;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
            GameObject.Find("Touch Panel").SetActive(false);
            rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
            // disable touch control
            audiosource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        }



        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
        }

        public void LaunchBall(Vector3 passedvelocity)
        {
            rigidbody.velocity = passedvelocity;
        }

        public void DropBall()  // This is attached to a button
        {
            rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            GameObject.Find("Touch Panel").SetActive(true);

        }
    }
```

As you can see above I have disable "Touch Panel" at start function. But on DropBall function ( remember it is attached to a button), I have set it to active but it is not working.Can anyone help me with this.Thanks.

EDIT:- This script is attached on a "Ball". and ball is attached on a Button.
"Touch Panel" is child of Canvas.

Comment: This script is on what object?

Comment: This script is attached on Ball and ball is attached on button

Comment: Okay, how about "Touch Panel" is it the parent of any of those. Maybe showing an image of you hierarchy will give more information.

Comment: @CNuts Canvas is parent of touch panel. and Ball is inside "Game Environment"

Comment: @CNuts Image is provided for easiness

Comment: @SamratLuitel Please start accepting answers if they answer your questions. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) is how to do it. You can do that to other answers that solved your problems too.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks I just learnt about this

Comment: Nice. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that when you disable your `Touch Panel` , `GameObject.Find` will not find it so you won't be able to enable it again.

[From the documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)

> This function only returns active GameObjects.

You need to setup your `Touch Panel` as a `public GameObject myPanel` and assign it in the inspector then you can enable and disable it.

```
myPanel.SetActive(false);
myPanel.SetActive(true);
```

Comment: So what shall I do.Create a public gameobject and attach it there

Comment: @SamratLuitel Exactly, that's how you should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Finally I solve it. I am feeling really stupid of myself